# Recursive solution for Minimum Path Sum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.

Eg: `[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]]`

Given the above grid map, return `7`. Because the path `1→3→1→1→1` minimizes the sum.

My solution using recursion but it is wrong, please help me correct it and explain what am I missing.

```
import math

def minPath(grid,n,m,a,b):
    if n>a or m>b:
        return math.inf
    grid[n][m] += min(minPath(grid,n+1,m,a,b),minPath(grid,n,m+1,a,b))
    return grid[n][m]

def minPathSum(grid):
    m = len(grid) - 1
    n = len(grid[0]) - 1
    a = m-1
    b= n-1
    minPath(grid,0,0,a,b)
    return grid[a][b]

print(minPathSum([[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]]))
```

Comment: remove double decrementing by 1 for borders and recheck if-condition (n>b,m>a)

Comment: @MBo can you elaborate please

Answer (score 0):

Remove double decrementing by 1 for borders and change if-condition

```
 if n>b or m>a:
 ....
 a = m    //2 for 3x3 map
 b = n
```

Possible main issue: if your grid is modified globally, you'll get wrong solution (perhaps your implementation makes local copy at every recursion call)

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add the successful condition, ie. if the recursive solution approach the final grid, then return the grid value

```
if n==a and m==b:
  return grid[n][m]
```

So the final solution should look like this:

```
import math

def minPath(grid,n,m,a,b):
    if n>a or m>b:
        return math.inf
    if n==a and m==b:
        return grid[n][m]
    return grid[n][m] + min(minPath(grid,n+1,m,a,b),minPath(grid,n,m+1,a,b))

def minPathSum(grid):
    m = len(grid) - 1
    n = len(grid[0]) - 1
    a = m-1
    b= n-1
    minPath(grid,0,0,a,b)
    return grid[a][b]

print(minPathSum([[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int minimumCostPath(vector<vector<int>> &path, int i, int j){
    int m = path.size() - 1;
    int n = path[0].size() - 1;
    if(i > m || j > n) return INT_MAX;
    else if(i == m && j == n) return path[i][j];

    int x = minimumCostPath(path, i + 1, j);
    int z = minimumCostPath(path, i , j + 1);



    int smallOutput = min(z, x) + path[i][j];

    return smallOutput;

  }
int main(){

    vector<vector<int>> path = { { 1, 2, 3 },{ 4, 8, 2 },{ 1, 5, 3 } };
    cout << minimumCostPath(path, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).